# How to create common '/ping' API resource in abstract BaseController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, abstract-class

I have BaseController:

```
@Controller
public abstract class BaseController {

    /**
     * The Logger for this class hierarchy
     */
    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ping", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ServiceResponse<?> ping() {
        ServiceResponse<Object> serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<>(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS);
        return serviceResponse;
    }
}
```

And few other Controllers that extend this BaseController like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value= "/admin")
public class AdminController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/all", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ServiceResponse<List<Account>> getAll() {
        ServiceResponse<List<Account>> serviceResponse = accountService.getAll();
        return serviceResponse;
    }
}
```

But as soon as I moved ping() resource BaseController I get errors on Server startup:

```
2016-04-23 21:31:39.862 ERROR 2335 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'clientController' method 
public ca.gatin.api.response.ServiceResponse<?> ca.gatin.api.controller.BaseController.ping()
to {[/admin/ping],produces=[application/json]}: There is already 'adminController' bean method
public ca.gatin.api.response.ServiceResponse<?> ca.gatin.api.controller.BaseController.ping() mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at ca.gatin.TodoAppApplication.main(TodoAppApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
```

It is just, I do not want to duplicate ping() resource in multiple Controllers. How can I move it to BaseController properly?

Comment: Do you want a ping mapping for every controller that extends BaseController (`admin/ping`, for example)? Or one `/ping` mapping, irrespective of how many BaseController subclasses you create?

Comment: I want ping method to be in a root of requestMapping like /ping

Answer (score 2):

I tlooks like you are using another

```
class ClientController extends BaseController
```

Both ClientController and AdminController map /ping to their inherited method ping(). Spring can map /ping only to the one or the other, thats why you get the exception.

You are writing

> I do not want to duplicate ping() resource in multiple Controllers

and there is no need to do this. Put your ping() method in its own controller, remove it from the BaseControler and thats it.

Anyway, I would not recomand to use inheritance in controllers, it makes things mostly more complicated than it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes you are right both ClientController and AdminController are extending BaseController. If I put ping() method to ClientController and AdminController then it will be duplication of same method in these to Controllers...